# WordPress widgetkit 4 slideshow dosen't work- how to edit css files path

Tags: css, wordpress, widgetkit

lately i received a WordPress website that was built by someone else and was ditched at the middle of process.

before they handed it to me they moved it to a new server.

the problem is that the slider at the front page does no receive the css and js files it needs.

when i download the website to my localhost the slider woks great.

this is the [link to the old server](http://talyuna.tempurl.co.il/new/) (the site is in a folder called 'new' which can cause the problem)

this is the [link to the new server](http://sparke.co.il/).

where can i control or edit the url path of the widgetkit 4 plugin?
how can i fix the problem?

tnx.